# Nginx rule for redirection error

Tags: redirect, nginx

I need to setup redirect rules for specific urls - I'm using NGINX.

Basically Something like this:

http://example.com/ --> http://example.com/maps

I' am trying:

```
location / {
proxy_pass http://maps-testmk;
include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
return 301 http://maps-testmk.mgr.ru/maps;
}
```

}

but I have - 500 err

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can identify specific URLs by using the `location =` syntax. For example:

```
location = / {
    return 301 /maps;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://maps-testmk;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
}
```

Only the URI `/` is redirected to `/maps`. All other URIs (including `/maps`) is sent upstream.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Answer (score 1):

May be like this:

```
location = / {
    return 301 http://maps-testmk.mgr.ru/maps;
}
location / {
    proxy_pass http://maps-testmk;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
}
```